# SQL in ArcGIS to compile a list of parcels adjacent to a specific parcel

Tags: sql, arcgis

I am having great difficulty with a query where I am using SQL in ArcGIS to compile a list of parcels, "FID", that are adjacent (touching/intersect) a specific parcel "FID".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FID =  "14368" <> '14368' AND Intersects(Shape, (SELECT Shape FROM Parcels WHERE FID = '14368'))

I tried the above but due to my lack of understanding of SQL I am not surprised if it is very wrong.

Comment: I've removed the tag spam. Only tag the technologies you are using; spamming conflicting technologies isn't helpful and is confusing.